# RecyclerView only changes after the screen goes off

Tags: java, android, json, localhost, android-volley

I first had a problem retrieving data from localhost then I added the code the

```
jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

I no longer got an error.

However the data is only displayed once the screen goes off and I put is back on.
Am I missing some line or code or should I remove some line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the key was to update the recycler adapter to inform it that the data has changed. 
With this line of code.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```